# PHP Amazon MWS API request Params

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to try the Amazon MWS PHP Example :

https://github.com/coopTilleuls/amazon-mws-products/blob/master/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Samples/GetMatchingProductSample.php

But I see nothing where I can put my ASIN List?

And where can I see the APPLICATION_NAME and APPLICATION_VERSION in the seller central? I cant find it.

Answer (score 3):

> But I see nothing where I can put my ASIN List?

Yeah, Amazon's documentation is pretty horrible.  Here's a code snippet that might help.  I recommend digging into the MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType object to learn more about it.

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$asinListObj = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$asinListObj->setASIN(ASIN_VALUE_HERE);
$request->setASINList($asinListObj);
invokeGetMatchingProduct($service, $request);
```

Another route entirely is to use some other service that'll handle all this mess for you like MegaMWS.com.  In that system, you just throw an ASIN at its API and it'll return product and offer details.  It's geared more towards books than anything else, but it's another option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, directly from Amazon, it will be more helpful:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html

APPLICATION_NAME and APPLICATION_VERSION can be anything, it's meant for identifying the application that you are writing.

There is also a PHP Library you can download that should be helpful: https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html/143-9515869-7910138

ASINList is part of your request as stated in the developer docs above.  Sorry, I'm not a PHP programmer, or I'd give you some code...